# show wordpress data without headers

Tags: headers

I need to use list of posts from wordpress in my project to generate XML.
I have my own php script. In this script i use

`require_once ('wp-blog-header.php');`

and i am retrieving list of posts

`$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );`

but in this case i can't use script as XML because there are some extra headers from wp-blog-header.php. Is there any way to include wordpress posts list without headers?

Comment: do you need to use `require_once ('wp-blog-header.php');`? You can make a template that can display xml...

Answer (score 0):

i found solution 
i am using this php code to send headers

```
header("Content-type: text/xml", true, 200);
```